# Can't ping sites or make curl request to some domains

Tags: linux, networking, curl, whm

I have a very serious problem with my whm. Anytime i reboot my server and run `/scripts/upcp --force`, i can be able to ping `lizzypay.com` and some other domain and curl works fine calling the domain(s) but after some hours i get curl error of connection timing out.

I am a wordpress plugin developer (expert) and i have done all i could even increasing my php maximum time out to 1500, done same on litespeed web admin console en all.

I still get "cURL error 28: Connection timeout after 10001 ms" when i use wordpress wp_remote_post() and i get "cURL error: Failed to connect to lizzypay.com port 443: Connection timed out" when i use php curl.

I have `set_time_limit(3000)` and even more. I have changed my DNS RESOLVER to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4, I have a valid ssl cert from lets encrypt which is expiring in the next 89 days.

I use Cloudlinux over Almalinux.

- changed dns resolver to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4
- increased my php time out
- reissues ssl certificate
- updated all services
- DISABLED FIREWALL (csf/imunify/firewalld) all disabled

Comment: You’re essentially reinstalling cPanel & WHM by running that command. I can’t help beyond that since the website you referenced appears not to be legitimate. I am uninterested in discussing that topic but reinstalling cPanel and WHM seems to have a side effect of unblocking a website.

Comment: You mean lizzypay appears to be not legitimate? Actually I consume lizzypay API for virtual top up via curl. Both lizzypay.com , bytebridge.com.ng, husmodata.com, ncwallet.ng doesn't work but hundreds of other users can consume their api

Comment: Yes; So I’ll explain the command you’re using. But beyond that I can’t help you.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your concern. At least I was able to get a response. Thanks

Comment: Try `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);` and `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400);` and also `set_time_limit(0);`. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11066378/165358).

Comment: okay let me try that and give a feedback

Comment: Its same here after trying that out